# This query fails once per month, how can it be refactored?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

This query fails once per month because the BETWEEN portion becomes invalid. Where `value BETWEEN min AND max`, on March 1 my query will fail again because it will compute to `partition_2 BETWEEN 28 AND 1`. How can this query be made more reliable but still only use the partitions required?

```
WITH recent_tasks AS
(SELECT task_id, state, timestamp, partition_0, partition_1, partition_2,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY task_id
               ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn
FROM firehose
WHERE
 "partition_0" BETWEEN to_char(current_date - interval '1' day, 'yyyy') AND to_char(current_date, 'yyyy')
 and "partition_1" BETWEEN to_char(current_date - interval '1' day, 'mm') AND to_char(current_date, 'mm')
 and "partition_2" BETWEEN to_char(current_date - interval '1' day, 'dd') AND to_char(current_date, 'dd')
ORDER BY rn)
SELECT * FROM recent_tasks
WHERE rn=1
```

A couple notes:

- Partitions are char values not integers
- partition_2 is the month partition
- The purpose of the query is to find the most recent state for each task_id
- Using AWS Athena
- Data is stored in S3 /yyyy/mm/dd format and each day is a new partition

Ideally my query would correctly handle monthly transitions:

```
BETWEEN FEB 10 AND FEB 11 (works with above)
BETWEEN FEB 28 AND MAR 1  (fails with above)
BETWEEN MAR 1 AND MAR 2   (works with above)
```

Comment: `WITH recent_tasks AS
(SELECT task_id, state, timestamp, partition_0, partition_1, partition_2,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY task_id` is only been support by MySQL 8.0.. And MySQL 8.0 isn't production ready yet.. you sure your are using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to achieve a zero instead of the 28:

```
cast(to_char(current_date, 'dd') as signed)-1
```

So, on 03/01, this will return a 1 - to_char(current_date, 'dd'), then subtracting it will give you a zero:

```
and "partition_2" BETWEEN to_char(cast(to_char(current_date, 'dd') as signed)-1) AND to_char(current_date, 'dd')
```